# Display the order date and time in the order list

Tags: prestashop

Please advise on the following problem I am facing:

On the order list display page in Prestashop 8.0, I would like the time of the order to be displayed in addition to the date of the order. Example: 2024-02-17 17:20:05. I tried to change it in Admin > Language > Short data, but the change is applied to the general mode in the whole store and I don't want that. The change must be made only on the page where the list of orders can be viewed...

It should be displayed in the form: 2024-02-17 17:20:05

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Changes on order list in PrestaShop 8 can be really hard to achieve. An alternative is to create your own controller to display a customized order list, in a module by your own.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it's possible with specific development, but lot of many override to do